# Getting a NameError for my class in Python

Tags: python, function, class, user-interface

My question is in the context of a GUI. I'm trying to create a program that sends simply emails with a GUI where a user can enter their email, pass and recipient email. I've coded both the GUI and the logic in a single file, separated by functions and both of them are in the same class. Is this a good idea?

Anyway, moving on. I want to set the "Send" command to the "send_email" method I created in the class, but it says it has not been declared. My code (with all the irrelevant stuff removed for this purpose) is below:

```
class Application(Frame):

    init, other widget creation\packing stuffs

    def create_widgets(self):
        widget creation methods...

        #For the send button
        self.send = Button(self.framepack, text="Send", width=10, command=send_email)
        self.send.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

    def send_email(self):
    email sending code...
```

Unfortunately a setup like this raises a `NameError` where the `send_email(self)` function has not been defined. The ONLY other way I can get my code to work is when I use a config method for the send button to add in the command as follow:

```
root = Tk()
app = Application(root)
app.send.config(command=app.send_email)
```

Is my program badly structured? How would you do it? Would you simply write this procedurally and skip the whole OOP approach? (Saves a LOT of repititive "self" mentions when creating\referring to variables this way).

Comment: did you try doing "self.send_email()"?

Comment: Post the actual code in its entirety -- "email sending code ..." does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
self.send = Button(self.framepack, text="Send", width=10, command=self.send_email)
```